# Indexing Excel files using Lucene

Tags: java, excel, apache, lucene

I have the following code. My first row contains all the attribute names and from the second row data is stored. Whenever I search for something I get 0 hits. I am new to lucene so please help[ me out

```
    try{  File inputFile = new File(str1);

 // DefaultComboBoxModel m1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
  // DefaultListModel m2 = new DefaultListModel();
 analyzer   = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
  index = new RAMDirectory();

 config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);

       w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
         XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
         ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sh.getRow(0);
    for (int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
    Cell cell = row.getCell(i, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
    list.add(cell.toString());
    } // LIST contains all the field values
    Iterator<Row> iter = sh.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Row row1 = iter.next();
    if (row1.getRowNum()==0)
        continue;
    for (int i=0;i<row1.getLastCellNum();i++){
   Cell cell1= row1.getCell(i, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
   list1.add(cell1.toString());
    //list1 contains data for every row
    // the size of list and list1 is always the same.
    }

    addDoc(w,list,list1);
    }
    w.commit();
    }catch(IOException e){}


  private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, ArrayList<String> list,ArrayList<String>     list1) throws IOException {

 // Document doc = new Document();
 for (int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
  doc.add(new TextField(list.toString(), list1.toString(), Field.Store.YES));
  w.addDocument(doc);
```

}

Comment: you're missing the `addDoc` method, which probably contains the code of interest

Comment: What does `addDoc(w,list,list1);` do?